# knitr: Show figure captions for multiple figures when setting figure dimensions using fig.width

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

tldr: How can I show figure captions for chunks with multiple figures when the dimensions are set with `fig.width` and `fig.height`?

I'm trying to use `rmarkdown` to create a pdf. Some of the chunks produce multiple figures, but the caption won't display if I use the `fig.width` chunk option to set the figure size.

Caption is displayed with `fig.width` if the chunk produces one figure:

````
```{r demo_1, fig.width=3, fig.cap="I work because I produce one plot, even though I use fig.width"}
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()
```
````

Caption is displayed with `out.width` if the chunk produces multiple figures:

````
```{r demo_2, out.width="50%", fig.show="hold", fig.cap="I work because I use out.width"}
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(tag="A")

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(tag="B")
```
````

Caption is not displayed with `fig.width` if the chunk produces multiple figures:

````
```{r demo_3, fig.width=3, fig.show="hold", fig.cap="I don't work because I set fig.width"}
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(tag="A")


iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(tag="B")
```
````